# Return values from sheet to listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

i am trying to get the listbox to return values from sheet. i have code to add the information to the sheet and essentially want to reverse it.

```
myvar = ""

For x = 0 To Me.Listlocation.ListCount - 1
    If Me.Listlocation.Selected(x) Then
    If myvar = "" Then
        myvar = Me.Listlocation.List(x, 0)
    Else
        myvar = myvar & ", " & Me.Listlocation.List(x, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next x

Sheets("Phonebook").Range("Data_start").Offset(TargetRow, 18) = myvar
```

I need help so that the listbox returns the value as selected.

I have tried

`with  Data_UF.listprogram.additem.Sheets("Phonebook").Range("Data_start").Offset(TargetRow, 18).value`

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like below. Please make sure `Data_UF.listprogram` is the correct reference of the listbox control.

```
Data_UF.listprogram.AddItem Sheets("Phonebook").Range("Data_start").Offset(TargetRow, 18).Value
```

Comment: This worked when i changed the listbox from rowsource to additem. 
Its not exactly what I wanted, but it will do the trick thank you.